# Firefox is displaying percentage widths incorrectly

Tags: css

I have a page with 3 td's all set at 33.333333% width. For some reason, in Firefox it's computing it as an actual pixel value of 568px, which makes the containers run off the page. I don't see anywhere with a fixed width being defined. Any ideas why this is happening? Is this a percentage-width bug in FF? Thanks!

http://gator3316.hostgator.com/~smartear/utilities/

Comment: Include relevant code to the question.

Comment: You might had to add the initial code not just url - fyi

Comment: This is a bad place to be using tables. You aren't presenting tabular data, you are using them to make columns. You should be using floated or inline `div`s, use the Flexbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `table td img { width:100%; }`

Comment: This was exactly it--Firefox was using the actual pixel widths of the image, and adding that 100% forced it into the container's percentage width. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `max-width: 100%` for the images, use `width: 100%`.  This will make the images take up the width of the parent whereas `max-width` will be ignored and the image will be the size of the actual image file itself.

I think this would also be an appropriate time to use [flex boxes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes), assuming you only need to support [browsers that support it](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex).

Answer (score 0):

the table also needs to be define in percentage(parent) in order to have the tds be listened to...Firefox assumes...so:

Include a **percentage** and a **table layout** like this:

```
table {
border-collapse: separate;
border-spacing: 0;
table-layout: fixed;
width: 100%;
}
```